# JavaScript .toggle - vertical scrollbar goes up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle-area").click(function() {
    $("#show-area").toggle(300);
  });
});
```

It displays some text when user click on the link. The problem is I have 12 links, one below the other, and the vertical scrollbar appears. However, when I scroll down and click on the 12th link (for example), my scrollbar jumps on the top of the page and I have to scroll down until the end to see the text that appeared.

How do I avoid this jump, and keep my list where it was before the click?

Here is the link - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpte6tkf/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to know about this http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Could you make an example page (like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/)) to show what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to skip the default hyperlink behaviour.
suppose #toggle-area are a hyperlink element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#toggle-area").click(function(e) {
    $("#show-area").toggle(300);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```